pdfBox extract xfdf from pdf
I have a text PDF file that is annotated (underlined, highlighted, etc).
This pdf file does not contain any forms.
I am trying to extract the xfdf as a string using apache pdfBox, so I can persist the string to a database.
This is what I have up until now, but it does not add the annotations correctly. Using ExportXFDF does not work because my pdf does not contain form data, only text. So AcroForm is null.
private String extractXFDF(Path path) throws ProcessingException {
    try (PDDocument pdfDoc = Loader.loadPDF(new RandomAccessReadBufferedFile(path.toFile().getAbsolutePath()));
         FDFDocument fdfDoc = new FDFDocument();
    ) {
        List<FDFAnnotation> fdfAnnotations = extractAnnotations(pdfDoc);
        fdfDoc.getCatalog().getFDF().setAnnotations(fdfAnnotations);
            
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        fdfDoc.saveXFDF(writer);
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

THe method extractAnnotations() returns a list of FDFAnnotation correctly.
This is the response I get from this extractXFDF() method:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
</xfdf>

Can anyone help me out what I could change to make it work?
Thanks in advance.

@KJ I do understand that xfdf is designed for fields data. And also that fdf is simpler. But your comment does not answer my question, if it is possible to extract the annotations as xfdf (or fdf) from a pdf that is annotated but does not have fields/forms.

I looked into the source code, FDFDictionary.writeXML() gets the fields, but not the annotations, so that would be a "no". So the question is now, is this part of the XFDF specifcation? If yes, it is easy to implement?

Based on what is written here in PDF, FDF and XFDF - GENERAL (5.4.1.), it is?
https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:19444:-1:ed-1:v1:en
I don't see an easy way to implement it other than going through the list of annotations and manually generating the xml elements, but that is error-prone work.

It turns out I have the xfdf specifcation. It would be a lot of work, although not difficult. Each fdf annotation class (e.g. FDFAnnotationSquiggly.java) will need its own writeXML() method.
